# Node.js -- Questions about fields in a POST

Tags: node.js

I am looking at this Gist (trying my hand at slightly more difficult Node than normal (I know this is still pretty simple :P )): https://gist.github.com/833401

I was wondering why we must specify the

```
connection.write('?track=' + this.track);
```

at the end?  It has already been established in the request URL.  Is this behavior specific to Twitter's API, or is this some sort of Node semantics with POST requests in Node?

Looking forward to your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's specific to twitter API. You generally don't need to do something like this with normal post requests.

Comment: The call to write() is the only one necessary in a normal Node POST, correct? No need to encode the params into the request URL as well?

Comment: Yes, it is the only thing needed.